# Has anybody had this problem - jquery not working with Magento in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, magento, magento-1.5

I'm running Magento 1.5.1.0 and have included a jquery image fader on the home page, running on my testing server. It works perfectly in Ie and chrome but does not work in Firefox.

If i enable Template Path Hints it will run the script ok turn it of and it does'nt run.

I'm getting no errors in firebug or firefox.

I have this code in the head.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/
1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(document).ready(function() {
 $j('#s3slider').s3Slider({
  timeOut: 4000
});
});



//]]>
</script>
```

And i have this at the top of my page.xml file:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery-1.4.2.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

I have also cleared the cache in Magento and firefox.

Has anybody got any ideas ??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're loading three versions of jQuery (1.3.2, 1.4.2, and an unknown version). Start by loading just one jQuery.

Comment: Are you loading the s3Slider plugin also?

Comment: thanks will try with just one !

Comment: Yes I'm loading the s3Slider ok because its workin ok in IE ?

Comment: Have now lost css in firefox !! dont think it is related to changes to jquery , don't know what is going on ! anybody ??

Comment: Have fixed problem and is now working , now just running the googleapis 1.6.4 version , also had stray <!-- which was commenting out some of the css files !!!

Comment: ?? not sure what you mean , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading three versions of jQuery:

- 1.3.2: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/
  1.3.2/jquery.min.js`.
- 1.4.2: `jquery-1.4.2.min.js`.
- and an unknown version: `jquery.js`.

You should only load one and that should probably be a version more recent than 1.4.2. Try just loading the most recent (1.6.4) from Google's CDN:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying ! I have done what you have suggested and is now working perfectly !! many thanks for your help...